# How do i reset the scroll of a div when you stop hovering over link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is when you mouse out over the dropdown menu items the scroll wheel gets reset. I've tried several options that I've been able to find online yet I cant seem to get it to work.

Is there anyone who has an idea of how to do this?

```
function resetScroll(){
   var scrollPosition = document.getElementsByClassName('list_in_column');
   console.log(scrollPosition);
   scrollPosition.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Amyttyl/uyh5g7zo/

I've tried the [ScrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) and [ScrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) functions in jQuery but they don't seem to work for me. I'm only a beginner at jQuery so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: try using this code `scrollPosition[0].scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: That doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: You have to call function with class name, not element name, `scrollToTop('mega-drop-down')`

Comment: So in my html like this?    <li class="mega-drop-down" onmouseleave="scrollToTop('mega-drop-down')">  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Mega Menu</a> ? that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: Absolutely, and try to writ more clear code

Comment: A cheaty and not so great way of doing what you want to accomplish is removing and re-adding the menu to the DOM, it will reset everything including scroll.

Comment: I cant cheat my way to do it since this piece of code will be used in the main website. @suman it doesnt work, also what do you mean write more clear code?

Answer (score 1):

The `display:none` that i was using on my menu made it so that scroll to did not work. changing the `display:none` to `opacity: 0` & `pointer-events: none;` and using this javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mega-drop-down').forEach(dropdown => {
        dropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', (element) => {
            dropdown.querySelector('.row').scrollTo({
                top: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });
        });
    }
);
```

made it work well as you can see in the following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/9c7g86w1/